Density of states in disordered chain model
I am trying to understand whether the density of states $g \left( E \right)$ of the system described by the infinite disordered chain Hamiltonian
$$H = \sum_n V_n \left| n \right\rangle \left\langle n \right| + \sum_n J \left( \left| n \right\rangle \left\langle n + 1 \right| + \left| n \right\rangle \left\langle n - 1 \right| \right) $$
can be described by the density of states $g \left( V \right)$ of the on-site potentials $V_n$. For example, if $g \left( V \right)$ was given by a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, would $g \left( E \right)$ also follow the same distribution?
